# How to call itcl::scope for an arbitrary object of the current class?

Tags: oop, scope, tcl, incr-tcl

[`itcl::scope`](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/itcl/scope.html) returns the full name of the specified member variable of `$this`.

How can I call [`itcl::scope`](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/itcl/scope.html) for another object of the same class (not for `$this`)?

Here is a workaround.

```
itcl::class dummy {
    variable m_data

    method function { other } {
        if { [itcl::is object -class dummy $other] } {
            error "Invalid argument."
        }

        set name "@itcl $other [$other info variable m_data -name]"
        # OR
        set name [lreplace [itcl::scope m_data] 1 1 $other]

        puts "==== this is the name of m_data of of object $other: $name"
    }
}
```

But this is ugly, to put it mildly.

I suppose `$other info variable m_data -name` should return what I want, but it just omits the object's context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a nice way to get that information, nor is it necessarily a good thing to make one. It's normally better to regard the variables of an object as being part of the implementation of that object, and not part of its interface. As such, external code shouldn't poke around inside like that; if it's important that something outside the object (including other members of the class) access the variables, write a method to return the reference to the variable (as generated with `itcl::scope`).

```
itcl::class dummy {
    variable m_data

    protected method dataRef {} { itcl::scope m_data }

    method function { other } {
        if { [itcl::is object -class dummy $other] } {
            error "Invalid argument."
        }

        set name [$other dataRef]

        puts "==== this is the name of m_data of of object $other: $name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, member variables should be a part of implementation, not the interface. But member functions of a class has to be able to see member variables of ALL objects of that class (not only ones of `$this` object).

Comment: @Vahagn: That's something that I'm not 100% sure I agree with. I don't know exactly how to express my problems with it without writing a whole essay on the subject though, and I've not time to do that today…